# Is my R formula equivalent to the statistical model I have in mind?

Tags: r, formula

**Problem:**

Building statistical models using `formula` is a powerful and elegant feature of the R language.
One of the reasons I haven't used `formula` as much as I should is that the syntax is a bit confusing (for example `x*y` does not simply mean "the product of `x` and `y`").

**Question:**

I am looking for a method to make sure that I have used the `formula` syntax correctly and that the `formula` I entered really implements the statistical model I have in mind. Ideally, I would like to have this confirmation before actually fitting the model.

**Example:**

Say, I want to find the parameters `a` and `b` of the model `y = a + b*(x1*x2)` by linear regression. Naively, I enter this in R

```
df <- data.frame(y=seq(5), x1=runif(5), x2=runif(5)) # toy data
lm(y~x1*x2, data=df)    # this is wrong
```

I can tell from the output of `lm` that this is not what I wanted because of the extra coefficients for `x1` and `x2`. But it should be possible to debug the formula before calling the fitting function. (The correct way to fit this model would be `lm(y~x1:x2, data=df)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you can *debug* a formula before you run the model is by using `formula` and `update`:

```
f <- formula( y ~ x1*x2)
update( f , terms( f ) )
# y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2

f <- formula( y ~ x1:x2)
update( f , terms( f ) )
# y ~ x1:x2
```

Coincidentally you can also specify the intercept term in your model (i.e. the coefficient for `a`) by including a 1 (1* `a` = `a`) so this is equivalent:

```
f <- formula( y ~ 1 + x1:x2)
update( f , terms( f ) )
# y ~ x1:x2
```